# How can I disable the code-lense feature that cause the "Add Debug Configuration" text from popping up in my editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

When I create new `.js` files in VS Code, an ***"Add Debug Configuration"*** button pops up. I tried to disable it, but I seem unable to figure out how I can configure V.S. Code so that the button does not appear anymore.
I'm using VSCode on Mac.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: search for a CodeLens setting

Answer (score 1):

For starters, @RioV8 is correct, this is a CodeLens configuration that you need to find, and change. I have posted the names of the exact CodeLens settings that will work for you, to be more specific, the following configuration posted in the code block below will work for getting rid of the **"Debug" & "Run"** **CodeLens** Popups for all JavaScript & TypeScript files. Just add the settings, configured as you see them, to either your workspace, or user, ***`settings.json`*** file:

---

```
    // settings.json

    {
        "javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false
        "typescript.implementationsCodeLens.enabled": false
        "debug.javascript.codelens.npmScripts": "never"
    }
```

###### NOTE on NPM Scripts:

---

###### The `"debug.javascript.codelens.npmScripts": "never"` setting is added to the configuration above, because, despite turning of the JS & TS CodeLenses, if your using a `package.json` file, NPM can, and will (especially if you use task created by the NPM package.json scripts property), prompt CodeLens words 'Debug' & 'Run' to popup again, however, it will only pop-up in your package.json file, and not in the actual JS & TS files themselves.